# Javascript grouping of option of select by optgroup

Tags: javascript, optgroup

i am trying to group my option values in optgroups. I currently have the options saved as
--model--
AUDI#A4 (2003-2009)
AUDI#A5 (2003-2009)
VW#Passat B7 (2003-2009)
VW#Passat B8 (2003-2010)

With JS they should be grouped like:
--model--
AUDI
A4 (2003-2009)
A5 (2003-2009)
VW
Passat B7 (2003-2009)
Passat B8 (2003-2010)

I have the following code which builds the options

```
      for (var i=0;i<l;i++){
      var opt = options[i].split('#');
        select[0].options[i+1] = new Option(opt[1],options[i]);

    }
```

I can manage to split the text of  option by the charachter # and add the first option after the default option/text "--model--". Can someone please help with grouping with optgroup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the data you are getting is in an array

Comment: the value for example "AUDI#A4 (2003-2009)" is stored in database as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting data form your database in the form of an array you can do something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>make select element</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let arr = [
            "AUDI#A4 (2003-2009)",
            "AUDI#A5 (2003-2009)",
            "VW#Passat B7 (2003-2009)",
            "VW#Passat B8 (2003-2010)"
        ]
        let tempObj = {}
        arr.forEach(val =>{
            let newVal = val.split("#");
            if (tempObj[newVal[0]] === undefined) {
                tempObj[newVal[0]] = [newVal[1]]
            }else{
                tempObj[newVal[0]].push(newVal[1])
            }
        })
        let selectElement = document.createElement("select");

        for (const val in tempObj) {
            let createOpt = document.createElement("optgroup");
            createOpt.setAttribute("label",val)

            tempObj[val].forEach(value =>{
                let option = document.createElement("option");
                option.innerText = value;
                createOpt.appendChild(option);
            })
            selectElement.appendChild(createOpt);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(selectElement);

            
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```